# Consumer that checks authentication state breaks when navigating to other screens

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-navigation

Users of my app need to authenticate. The authentication state is tracked by a provider class. The login functionality works fine, however, users can also logout, and that is giving problems.

In main.dart I use a consumer widget to track the authentication state:

```
child: Consumer<AuthenticationProvider>(
    builder: (ctx, auth, child) => MaterialApp(
      title: 'FlutterChat',
      home: auth.isAuth
          ? WelcomeScreen()
          : FutureBuilder(
              future: auth.tryAutoLogin(),
              builder: (ctx, authResultSnapshot) =>
                  authResultSnapshot.connectionState ==
                          ConnectionState.waiting
                      ? SplashScreen()
                      : AuthFlowScreen(),
            ),
    ),
  ),
```

At app start, the consumer will check the authentication state, if the user is not authenticated, then the user will be redirected to AuthFlowScreen, else the user will see the WelcomeScreen. If the user followed the AuthFlowScreen and successfully authenticates, the user will automatically go to the WelcomeScreen, because that is what the Consumer does.

The WelcomeScreen has a NavBar from which the user can navigate to other parts of the app. The NavBar also has a button to Logout. When this is pressed, the consumer in the main.dart file needs to react. As long as the user didn't navigate to any other screen, the logout works and the AuthFlowScreen is shown to the user. However, if the user navigated to other parts in the app, this does not happen.

Navigation happens with:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return ChatOverviewScreen();
              }))
```

Logout script:

```
void logout() {
  _auth.signOut();
  _userEmail = null;
  _userId = null;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

It seems that the navigation is messing up the consumer in the main.dart file, however, how can I navigate through the app, such that the consumer in main.dart is still working.

Answer (score 0):

for login system better to use bloc state management, you can find full example here :
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial